# Simple javascript browser checker

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I know this is simple, but I can't seem to get this to work. 
When the page loads, it checks the browser. if its chrome I want it to hide a div, but show it if its anything else.

it detects the browser ok, since i checked using alerts, but the hiding bit doesn't.
Can you help

```
function browserTest() {
    var browser = /Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (browser) {
        document.getElementById("chromeBox").style.visibility = "hidden";
        //alert("chrome");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('chromeBox').style.visibility = 'visible';
        //alert("not chrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `visibility` hides the content but keeps the space where the element is ? `display:none` should be used to hide the element and its space

Comment: If you do a `console.log(document.getElementById("chromeBox"));`, do you have an element that match that ID?

Comment: We need your html code too.

Comment: `but the hiding bit doesn't` how do you know it does not work? chromeBox div is still shown or what? Also - where do you call your `browserTest` function? Does it happens in `onload` or at the end of page, or it is in head of page?

Comment: What happen if you `alert(document.getElementById("chromeBox"))` (or better, `console.log`)?

Comment: Code seems to fine.Make sure div has id exactly as `chromeBox` and not something like `chromebox` or `ChromeBox`.`id` attribute is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we cant figure out what happens with your DOM so here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/uwc3B/2/

Here is the code:

**JavaScript**

```
function browserTest() {
    var browser = /Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (browser) {
        document.getElementById("chromeBox").style.visibility = "hidden";
        //alert("chrome");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('chromeBox').style.visibility = 'visible';
        //alert("not chrome");
    }
}
browserTest(); //should be called on DOM ready
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="chromeBox">
It's not Chrome!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chromeBox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You should call `browserTest` at the end of the body or on DOM ready.

Answer (score 1):

You may have few problems here:

1) `browserTest` is executed before div is actually load (if it is executed in `<head>` section with code like below, for example):

```
<head>
  <script>
     function browserTest() { .... }
     browserTest(); - div is not loaded here yet and getElementById will return nothing.
  </script>
```

To fix this - put that script section after chromeBox div html markup
or execute browserTest in onload event (that will guaranty that div is already loaded and getElementById will find it):

```
<head>
  <script>
     function browserTest() { .... }         
  </script>
....
</head>
<body onload="browserTest()">
  ....
```

2) Check if your div really has an ID `chromeBox`. IDs are case sensitive, so `document.getElementById("chromeBox")`  will not find `<div id="ChromeBox">`

Remember that visibility:hidden will make a div invisible, but space for it will be still reserved. Maybe you should better use style.display = "none"/style.display = "block"

Also, learn how to use developer tools. All browsers have it. For firefox you may need to install Firebug. Just call it using F12 and check console to see if any error is shown there.

Comment: Moving the script after the div made it work. Thanks a lot, its been annoying me for a while now

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - that is what you should do instead of `thank you` commenting. And I would advice to use onload approach. That is better solution.

Comment: @FAngel `onload` should only be used as a failback solution after `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: @metal_fan onload and domcontentloaded are different events. So, why it should be used `only` as a failback solution?

Comment: @metal_fan actually, for this case DOMContentLoaded may be even better, because onload may happen much later after `chromeBox` is actually. But if I need image sizes for you JS code - DOMContentLoaded is not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot everyone. its working now, just needed to call the function after the div. I'm new to javascript, so I'm still making basic errors like this.

Thanks